# Building Curl with LIBEAY32.lib still inserts LIBEAY32.dll into my project's import section

Tags: curl, dll, linker, openssl, libcurl

I've inserted both libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib as additional dependencies but during run time, over other machines which don't have OpenSSL installed, I'm prompted with the following error:

[image]

and this is how i configured it in my main project:
[image]

But a quick view with depends, showing the following dependencies:
[image]

libCurl itself was compiled and built only using SSL precompiled headers.

```
WIN32;NDEBUG;BUILDING_LIBCURL;CURL_STATICLIB;USE_SSLEAY;USE_OPENSSL;
```

The actual SSL linkage was done by the main project, which linked curl as well.

Comment: Perhaps you're building libCurl as a static library?